# Сортировка записей по целочисленному мета полю

Tags: wordpress, циклы, meta

Есть цикл записей произвольного типа. Хочу сортировать их по мета полю, по всем документациям код должен быть такой, но он не сортирует записи никак.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'loan',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'order_by'      => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'      => 'interest_rate_min',
        'order'         => 'ASC'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет такого параметра 'order_by'. Есть 'orderby'.